# Strongly type object properties to be dependent on other object properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to strongly type a React Context object, and I want one of the properties to be dependant on another. For example, I'm making a ModalContext, and I'm using a similar pattern to Redux actions, where there's a type and payload, but I call them `modalType` and `modalData`, so that I can pass data to the modal through context. So, here's some examples...

If `modalType = 'LOGIN MODAL'`, then pass no data, just show login form in modal.

If `modalType = 'RENT MOVIE'`, then `modalData = {movieId: 123456}` so the modal knows which movie to show.

In a site admin context, if `modalType = 'RESET USER PASSWORD'`, then `modalData = {userId: 456789}` so the modal can show that user.

Here's my context interface.

```
interface IModalContext {
  visible: boolean; 
  modalType:''|'LOGIN MODAL'|'RENT MOVIE'|'EDIT USER'; 
  modalData: any; 
}
```

How on earth do I make `modalData` dependant on the value of `modalType`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an union for this:

```
type IModalContext = 
  | {
    visible: boolean;
    modalType: 'LOGIN MODAL',
  }
  | {
    visible: boolean;
    modalType: 'RENT MOVIE',
    modalData: { movieId: number }
  }
  | ...
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing for now. I just feel like it's clunky and someone smarter than myself could come up with something more clever. Thanks for your suggestion!